# Draw a line away from "google map navigation path" at fixed distance on both the side, so it will create box like view around navigation path

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-directory-api

How can we Draw a line away from "google map navigation path" at fixed distance on both the side, so it will create box like view around navigation path. is it possible?

Please check the attached image to be more clear with requirement, where blue line is my navigation path between two point & red line is that suppose to be plot around the path at fix distance

[[image]]

Also I have use 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&name=cruise&key=Key' to get place list around selected location. But is it possible to get all place detail for whole path, like all the restaurant that are 1KM away from displayed navigation path. is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

For the ***"box like view around the navigation path"***, it's possible by using  the [Google Maps API - Shapes - Polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes#polygons). From the doc:

> ...**polygons** are designed to **define regions within a closed loop** with the interior filled in.

You just have to define the points for the outline of the polygon. I think here, you can use the location of the ***navigation path*** as center, to be the basis of where you'll put the `polygon` points.

While for the ***"is it possible to get all place detail for whole path, like all the restaurant that are 1KM away from displayed navigation path"***, yes, it's possible. As seen in the sample URL you provided on your post:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&name=cruise&key=Key`

-- you are already defining the `radius`(*500m*) and the `type`(*restaurants*). What you could do is do a request for each points you think is relevant in the ***navigation path*** then consolidate the necessary data from the response. You can see the [Place Details docs](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id#place-details) for more details.

I think it'll be easier if you just choose the center of the navigation path, then provide the radius that will cover it all, but I guess you still prefer the way I mentioned above. Anyways, all formulas and calculations will be up to you. Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: 1. I have already used Poly-lines to plot navigation path, but to plot parallel line to existing line we need new co-ordinate, how can we get those?   2.yes, This can be solution to call same PLACE API with new co-ordinates on path after fix interval, so all over we can cover full path. but this will take to much loading time as in there are so many points in case of long route.

Comment: 1. As per my suggestion in the post, you can use the `polyline` points to use as basis for the center and do some calculations on where to plot out the lines around it, like add a value to the `LatLng` of the navigation path so set around the points around it. 2. It'll be a lot of request, but so far, I think it is the only way I can think of on how to do the specification you provided (unless like what I posted just get the center of the navigation path and increase the radius that can cover it, I think the users themselves would decide to go to the closest resto, still your're choice tho)

Comment: Also, what I was suggesting at first was drawing a single `polygon`  around the navigation path, but I think it's also okay to do two `polylines` (above and below) or four (above, below, left, right) if it's less confusing.. I think.. then just connect them.

Comment: Helpful, But it will be great if you can provide some refer to plot line away from existing line.